# How to keep ubuntu image running?

Tags: docker

I try to start container with following command

```
sudo docker run ubuntu
```

after that I checked with

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

found the container exited already

why does it exit?

How could I keep it running in backgroud without specifying -it and attach to it on demanding?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Solved by myself, a elegant way to keep the container running and waiting for further "attach" or "exec" is the following (to keep the STDIN open by -i option)

```
docker run -i -d ubuntu
```

Comment: To get back into the container one it's running (because I forget every time): `docker exec -it [container_id_or_name] bash`

Comment: Pro Tip: Dont use sudo.
See [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user).

Comment: They are just exiting.  -i -d does not change it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to start an application with the docker run command that won't exit.

Example:

`docker run -d --entrypoint '/bin/bash cat'  ubuntu`

Comment: @Micheal this returns error "Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 2bb0e1b79d10401023d465580dcc2bfa2f18d58cefed7d02c13ed879c8717f47: [8] System error: exec: "/bin/bash cat": stat /bin/bash cat: no such file or directory"

Comment: I had errors, but this worked `docker run -d ubuntu '/bin/bash /bin/cat'`

Comment: I had the same problem, but I found useful using as entrypoint '/bin/bash tail -f /dev/null'. It could be used also in Dockerfile as CMD tail -f /dev/null. Thanks to http://bigdatums.net/2017/11/07/how-to-keep-docker-containers-running/

Answer (score 3):

You can add the tail command while running the container.

```
docker run -d ubuntu tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: Good hack . But is there any other way?

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti Can you share more about why do you want to keep it running? I mean are you running any service. 
This way I can provide more relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is

(from `docker run --help`)

`docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

you have forgotten to specify a command.

You should have a look at the docker hub

https://registry.hub.docker.com/

For example for nginx, if you look at

https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

you will find

`docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -d nginx`

If you look at

https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/7f3ef0927ec619d20181e677c97f991df0d7d446/Dockerfile

you will notice that the last line of the Dockerfile is

`CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

This means that when you launch the docker image nginx, the implicit action is to start nginx.

Answer (score -3):

If you want the container to not exist, you have to use the `-d` argument

So it look like this:

```
docker run -d ubuntu
```

Comment: tested with -d  still exit

Comment: You need to show the output if you want more help :) `docker ps -a`

Comment: I don't like downvoting, but I did in this case because `-d` does _not_ cause the container to "not exist". Rather, it causes it to run "detached", meaning "in the background", giving you the shell back, and not exiting when the launching terminal exits.